# Multivariate linear regression in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a data set as follows arranged in `X` and `Y` matrices as follows:
[image]

I want to find a `2*2`matrix `A` such that `y_i=A x_i` for all `i=1,...,n`. So I am using the following code for linear regression in python:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sklearn
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model

#n=5
X=np.random.uniform(0,1,(2,5))
A=np.random.uniform(0,1,(2,2))
y=np.dot(A,X)
print(y)

# Create linear regression object
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
# Train the model using the training sets
model=regr.fit(X, y)
#model.predict(X)
model.coef_
```

However my `model.coef_` command is printing a `5*5` matrix instead of a `2*2` matrix that I want for `A`. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Fit the model on a transpose of the samples and outcome - the second dimensions will be used to create the model - to get a 2x2 array:

```
model=regr.fit(X.T, y.T)
# test
np.testing.assert_allclose(y.T, model.predict(X.T))
```

Comment: Then the model parameter `model.coef_` should be actually `A^T` of the original matrix `A` right? But surprisingly it is exactly the same.

Comment: Why would you want that? If they are the same size, I wouldn't expect them to not be the same. BTW, transpose does not work like so with multiplication

Comment: No I meant that when I printed `model.coef_` it returned the matrix `A` exactly but it should actually be `A.T` right? This is because `y=A.x` implies `x.T=A.T y.T`

Comment: No, coefficients come after the independent vars in linear regression: `y.T =  x.T A`.  Some matrix algebra :)